NestedTables and how to apply logic based on a list in Power Apps
I have a Table in Dataverse called Drivers that has DriverName, Jsonvalues. In my Jsonvalues looks like the following
{
"Month": "Jan",
"Year": 2024,
"Value": 31
},
{
"Month": "Feb",
"Year": 2024,
"Value": 27
}.
I have a Set called DriverNames which in this instance only has Volume, Price and Rates and a set called operators which can be any math operator in this example its * and /. Based on DriverNames I want to pull the Json Values for each Driver and use the operators to get a final value.
So far I have parsed them into one collection called DriverCollection which is DriverName, Month, Value and Year and grouped them by Month and Year.
I can't figure out how to use my operator in the nested tables or even if this is the right way to go about solving the process. Final goal would be to have Volume * Rate / Price in each nested table as Output and then create a new collection to just extract month year and output/


Thanks
